# How get price and paisa from rupee without using Arithmetic operation?

Tags: swift

I've price,

`let value: UInt32 = 6500085`

In the number `6500085` the last two digits are fixed to paisa and the remaining is rupee.  In this constant, the paisa is 85 and the rupee is 65000. The paisa is strictly always 5's combination. 0,5,10,15...95

I don't need `Double` but price `String`

I am able to do this esily using

```
let price: UInt32 = 6500085 // ₹65000.85
let paisa: UInt32 = price % 100
let rupee: UInt32 = price / 100
let string = "\(rupee).\(paisa)"
```

But I am curious is there any way to get same string using BitWise AND Operation or Shift operations like below wrong code?  I believe  BitWise AND or SHIFT is a more performant way than using the arithmetic operation I've used.

```
let value: UInt32 = 6500085
let paisa = value & 0xFF
let rupee = (value >> 8)
print("Rupee: \(rupee), Paisa: \(paisa)")
```

Comment: You cannot mix decimal and binary arithmetic. Decimal 6500085 is hexadecimal 0x632EF5